# Optimizing bulk deletion and creation of NSManagedObjects

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, bulkinsert, nsnotificationcenter

When a user downloads my app, and 'signs up' we populate Core Data with user data, which could run into potentially thousands of objects.

We also have a 'log out' option for the user, at which time we bulk delete these objects. (We do not delete the underlying sqlite stores because some of the data in there is not user specific, and we'd like to retain that).

What is common across both bulk creation and deletion is that these processes take a lot of time.

After performing obvious optimizations and using the Time Profiler instrument, I reached the conclusion that the biggest bottleneck seems to be this pattern:

```
- (void)awakeFromFetch {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(someSelector:) name:someNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)didTurnIntoFault {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

This seems to be taking 65-70% of all the CPU time during creation as well as deletion. I've tried to minimize the number of objects that get unfaulted on creation, but there is a minimum number that I cannot bring down further.

But for deletion, it seems an object that is marked to be deleted must be fetched, unfaulted, and then faulted again, and therefore `didTurnIntoFault` is called for all objects that are deleted. I do most of the object cleanup in `didTurnIntoFault`, but surprisingly, removing the object as an observer from the default NSNotificationCenter seems to be the heaviest operation (by a huge margin).

Any ideas why removeObserver: is turning out to be so heavy? Any ideas on how to optimize this for faster signup/log out?

Comment: Why not just create a new store when the user logs out.  Keep a new store with the seed data in it and just replace the store when the user logs out rather than deleting objects.  Or use two stores, one with the discardable user data and the other with data you want to retain and just replace the one with user data with an empty one.

Comment: Why do you even need thousands of objects? Maintain multiple stores and lazy load.

Comment: I'm not sure how multiple stores would help here as during creation and deletion I need to insert/delete all objects.

Answer (score 0):

NotificationCenter is a powerful tool that comes with some costs.  When you use it without a receiving/generating object (`object:nil` in your code) then things can go sideways and things start to get expensive.

So my first suggestion is to explore narrowing the scope of the notifications by adding an object.  Is there, hopefully, one object that throws those notifications you are receiving?  If so can you somehow pass that in?

Second thought would be to move the notifications out of the `NSManagedObject` entirely.  This would cause more work on your part so it is my second suggestion even though I recommend it more.  Consider having a controller that listens for the notification, has a reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` and then can do the appropriate work.

If neither of those are appropriate then a better understanding of what that notification is for is required.